# If f > 0, is ∫ f > 0?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is a measurable function such that $f > 0$.  Is the following a true assumption?

$$\int f \; du> 0$$

Comment: Please always tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be the measure space we are working with. Next, let us assume that $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and that $f(x) > 0$ for a.e. $x \in X$.

Assume, by way of contradiction, that $$\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu = 0.$$ Because $f$ is non-negative, this means that $$\int_X |f|\,\mathrm{d}\mu = 0.$$ Of course, this implies that $f = 0$ a.e. thereby contradicting the assumption that $f > 0$ a.e.

Answer (score 2):

For any $n\geq 1$, let $A_n$ be the set
$$A_n=\left\{ x \text{ such that } f(x)\geq \frac 1 n\right\}$$
[Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) implies that, 
$$\int f d\mu\geq \frac 1 n\mu(A_n)$$
So if you assume that $\int f d\mu=0$, then $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.
So $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\right)=0$$
this implies that $f=0$ almost everywhere.